# Reducing EMI from PWM controlled Led segments

Tags: microcontroller, led, pwm, emc

I am currently designing a product that has a ring of LEDs with 7 individually dimmable segments.(all together about 40 standard (blue/white)LEDs max 15mA each) the only supply voltage is 3.3v but I have considered a seperate Boost supply for the LEDs to minimize the power wasted by the resistors since i can only drive 1 LED per resistor at 3,3v. (but IMO not worth introducing a whole new supply thats also eating power and efficency by itself. haven't done the math yet)  The ring is very thin and the backside can't be populated besides a connector. There is really only space for the Diodes and their Resistors. On the control board there is a STM32(G070) providing the PWM. My current idea is connecting both PCBs via FPC/FFC 14 pin and assigning neighbouring supply and return for every segment driven by N MOS located on the control board.(keeping loop areas as low as possible)

Would reducing the rise time via gate resistors to a reasonable compromise be enough here?

I have also thought of filtering the Current carrying PWM to low frequency or even dc. but that takes a buck converter style circuit for every segment, so thats expensive an probably waaay overkill

I am not comfortable placing the mosfets on the ring itself because then I would have all PWM signal lines referencing a single ground return line. (Is that even a concern? ^^)

Am I possibly overthinking this?
The whole thing needs to pass EMI testing.

EDIT the cable will be 50mm long and the ring has a diameter of 90mm

Comment: The obvious answer to look at first is RC lowpass filters. And/or lowering the frequency as much possible.